"A, and thus B, is true." or "A, and thus B, are true."?
Both of these sound correct to my ear, but I am sure experts can come up with a convincing reason to conclude that one of them is not grammatically correct. ChatGPT reasons that one should use "are" because:

[...] “A, and thus B” is a complex subject, but it is considered singular because it expresses one complete thought or idea.

What do the human experts say?
PS: I often use such sentences in my math writings.

This post is quite different than mine. Mine has no parentheticals or em-dashes, and moreover, discusses a "consequential" subject rather than that of a "juxtapositive" nature. The latter is also the way my post differs from this one.

This question is similar to: Singular or plural verb after parenthetical material containing a conjunction?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (But see also She{,} as well as I{,} am/is/are/tired of the work.)

@EdwinAshworth To me, the two questions that you mentioned seem far from being related to mine. Nevertheless, I have tried to explain how so in the edit.

Regardless of whether it's explicitly enclosed in brackets, I think the highlighted element in A and thus B is... is a parenthetical. Just as it would be with and therefore B, and hence B, and B too, and also B,... Unquestionably it's a duplicate. Not that I'm impressed by the answers on the "original", but I'd say it's essentially an English Language Learners question anyway.

The question is not a duplicate of the two questions listed in the closing banner, because the use of parentheses is essential to both of them; this one does not involve parentheses in any way.

@jsw29 Araucaria writes at the second-mentioned thread 'Note that it doesn't seem to make any difference when the as well as section is marked of by commas.' Here and thus B is a parenthetical, whether offset by commas, dashes, brackets, or zero punctuation. And Araucaria states that there seems no consensus on what agreement is allowed. // The best way to avoid arguments from those in opposite camps is to rewrite:  "A is true, and thus so is B.'

If you moved the commas so that they broke out the word "thus [or less ambiguously, therefore]" instead of the phrase "and thus B," you'd have this sentence: "A and, therefore, B is/are true." In that case, I think, a majority of editors (and perhaps also writers) would prefer "are" to "is."
